# Integrability of vector-valued functions expressed in terms of partitions

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

**Question:**
Let $\mathbf{f}$ be a function $[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{k}$, and $\alpha:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ an increasing function.

- Show that $\mathbf{f}$ is integrable with respect to $\alpha$ if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a partition $P = \{x_{0}, \ldots, x_{n}\}$ of $[a, b]$ such that
  \begin{equation*}
      \sum_{i=1}^{n} \operatorname{diam}(\mathbf{f}([x_{i-1}, x_{i}])) \Delta \alpha_{i} < \epsilon
  \end{equation*}
  where "$\operatorname{diam}$" denotes the diameter of a set.

Assume $\mathbf{f}$ is indeed integrable with respect to $\alpha$, and let $\epsilon$ be a positive real number, and $P = \{x_{0}, \ldots, x_{n}\}$ a particular partition making the above inequality hold.

- Show that for every choice of points $t_{i} \in [x_{i-1}, x_{i}]$ ($i=1, \ldots, n$), we have
  \begin{equation*}
      \bigg|\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbf{f}(t_{i}) \Delta \alpha_{i}\bigg) - \bigg(\int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{f} d \alpha\bigg)\bigg| < \epsilon
  \end{equation*}

**My problem:**
I cannot work out the 2nd bullet and I know the inequality in the 2nd bullet holds if the partition is finer and finer, but I have no idea to prove it holds for this given partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $$M=\sum_{i=1}^n \text{diam}({\bf f}([x_{i-1},x_i]))[\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})]$$ and note that, by hypothesis, $M<\varepsilon$. Therefore $\varepsilon-M>0$.

Fix $\nu>0$ such that for any partition $\{y_0<\ldots<y_q\}$ of $[a,b]$ with $\max_i y_i-y_{i-1}<\nu$ and any $(s_i)_{i=1}^q\in \prod_{i=1}^q [y_{i-1},y_i]$, $$\Bigl|\sum_{i=1}^q {\bf f}(s_i)[\alpha(y_i)-\alpha(y_{i-1})] - \int_a^b {\bf f}d\alpha\Bigr|<\varepsilon-M.$$ Let $Q=\{y_0<\ldots<y_q\}$ be any partition with $\max_i y_i-y_{i-1}<\nu$. Let $R=Q\cup P$. Write $R=\{z_0<\ldots<z_r\}$ and fix $(s_i)_{i=1}^r\in \prod_{i=1}^r[z_{i-1},z_i]$.

There exist $0=m_0<\ldots<m_n=r$ such that $z_{m_i}=x_i$. We estimate \begin{align*}\Bigl|\sum_{i=1}^n {\bf f}(t_i)[\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})] - \int_a^b {\bf f}d\alpha\Bigr| & \leqslant \Bigl|\sum_{i=1}^n {\bf f}(t_i)[\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})]-\sum_{i=1}^r {\bf f}(s_i)[\alpha(z_i)-\alpha(z_{i-1})]\Bigr| \\ & +\Bigl|\sum_{i=1}^r {\bf f}(s_i)[\alpha(z_i)-\alpha(z_{i-1})] - \int_a^b {\bf f}d\alpha\Bigr|. \end{align*} We know the second of these two terms is less than $\varepsilon-M$. We will show that the first term is at most $M$, so the sum is strictly less than $M+\varepsilon-M=\varepsilon$.

To handle the first term, we note that, since $$\alpha(x_p)-\alpha(x_{p-1})=\sum_{i=m_{p-1}+1}^{m_p}\alpha(z_i)-\alpha(z_{i-1}) $$ and  $$\sum_{i=1}^r {\bf f}(s_i)[\alpha(z_i)-\alpha(z_{i-1})]=\sum_{p=1}^n \sum_{i=m_{p-1}+1}^{m_p} {\bf f}(s_i)[\alpha(z_i)-\alpha(z_{i-1})],$$

\begin{align*}\Bigl|\sum_{i=1}^n {\bf f}(t_i)[\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})] -\sum_{i=1}^r {\bf f}(s_i)[\alpha(z_i)-\alpha(z_{i-1})]\Bigr| & = \Bigl|\sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{i=m_{p-1}+1}^{m_p} {\bf f}(t_p)[\alpha(z_i)-\alpha(z_{i-1})] 
 \\ & - \sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{i=m_{p-1}+1}^{m_p} {\bf f}(s_i)[\alpha(z_i)-\alpha(z_{i-1})] \\ & \leqslant \sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{i=m_{p-1}+1}^{m_p}|{\bf f}(t_p)-{\bf f}(s_i)|[\alpha(z_i)-\alpha(z_{i-1})] \\ & \leqslant \sum_{p=1}^n \bigl[\text{diam}({\bf f}([x_{p-1},x_p]))\sum_{i=m_{p-1}+1}^{m_p}[\alpha(z_i)-\alpha(z_{i-1})]\bigr] \\ & = \sum_{p=1}^n \text{diam}({\bf f}([x_{p-1},x_p]))[\alpha(x_p)-\alpha(x_{p-1})]\\ &=M.
\end{align*}

Comment: which bullet did you prove?

Comment: This is the second bullet. You mentioned not being able to work out the second bullet, but you didn't mention the first, so I assumed you had that one covered.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask what \nu do in your proof?

Comment: $\nu$ is the control on the mesh (maximum subinterval length) of the fine partition $Q$. I have edited my answer to make the dependence on $\nu$ clearer. I have also edited the solution to give strict inequality $<\varepsilon$ instead of $\leqslant \varepsilon$.

Comment: The \nu only affects the selection of Q, but I think any Q with that inequality < \epsilon - M will also work, right?

Comment: What we need for the proof is that $P\cup Q$ satisfies the inequality $<\varepsilon-M$, for some sampling. However, knowing that $Q$ satisfies the inequality (for some sampling) doesn't necessarily mean that $P\cup Q$ will (or at least it's not obvious). Because sometimes you get "lucky" with a good sampling, even if the partition isn't very fine. EG take a line $y=x$ and sample with midpoints, the Riemann sum gives the exact value of the integral, no matter how fine the partition is. But other partitions which don't use the midpoint sampling could be far away from the value of the integral.

Comment: But yes, if $P\cup Q$ has **some** sampling which gives the inequality $<\varepsilon-M$, you can use that one and get the conclusion.

Comment: Then you must have some condition for \nu since for every Q we can find a \nu. Also, you assumed that there exists a partition Q to obtain the inequality.

Comment: I'm assuming you did the first integral. In which case for any $\mu$, we can find such a partition $Q$.

Notice that we don't actually care about the partition $Q$. We care about $P$. We just choose a very fine partition $Q$ and use it as an intermediate between the one we care about and the integral.